# Webpack searching in wrong subdirectory with relative import

Tags: typescript, vue.js, webpack, import, vuejs3

I have a Vue (v3 w/ TS) app nested within a directory (in `/my-vue-app`), and in the directory which contains this, there is another folder for my Node.js server code (not TS), which I am using to SSR the Vue app. Here is my directory structure:

```
- /app-container
    |
    - /app-container/.babelrc.json
    - /app-container/webpack.server.js
    - /app-container/my-vue-app
       |
       - /app-container/my-vue-app/babel.config.js
       - /app-container/my-vue-app/package.json
       - /app-container/my-vue-app/tsconfig.json
       - /app-container/my-vue-app/public
       - /app-container/my-vue-app/src
          |
          - /app-container/my-vue-app/src/App.ts
          - /app-container/my-vue-app/src/main.ts
          - /app-container/my-vue-app/src/views
             | -- some stuff
          - /app-container/my-vue-app/src/components
             | -- some stuff
          - /app-container/my-vue-app/src/router
             |
             - /app-container/my-vue-app/src/router/index.ts
    - /app-container/server
        |
        - /app-container/server/index.js
```

This all seems fairly standard, and I can import `/app-container/my-vue-app/src/App.ts` from `server/index.js` using `import App from '../vue-platform-app/src/App';`, as one would expect.

However, when I try to import `App.ts` from `main.ts`, I get a very strange error that the module is 'not found'. I've tried the following import syntaxes:

```
// This does not
import App from "./App";
// Throws error complaining about .ts extension
import App from "App.ts";
// As per `vue create`, @ is configured to /src
import App from "@/App"
// Understandably, this is not found - but it was worth a try
import App from "/my-vue-app/src/App"

// This worked
import App from "C:\\absolute\\path\\to\\app-container\\my-vue-app\\src\\App";
```

For the first one, `"./App"` (which is the one I, and my IDE, and Typescript, all expect to work), I found that Webpack seems to be searching in the wrong directory - for some reason, it's looking in `/my-vue-app/src/views` instead of just `/src`, and as such, it is not finding it. With `--stats verbose`:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './App' in 'C:\absolute\path\to\app-container\my-vue-app\src\views'
resolve './App' in 'C:\absolute\path\to\app-container\my-vue-app\src\views'
  using description file: C:\absolute\path\to\app-container\my-vue-app\package.json (relative path: ./src/views)
    using description file: C:\absolute\path\to\app-container\my-vue-app\package.json (relative path: ./src/views/App)
      no extension
        C:\absolute\path\to\app-container\my-vue-app\src\views\App doesn't exist
      .tsx
        C:\absolute\path\to\app-container\my-vue-app\src\views\App.tsx doesn't exist
      .ts
        C:\absolute\path\to\app-container\my-vue-app\src\views\App.ts doesn't exist
      .js
        C:\absolute\path\to\app-container\my-vue-app\views\App.js doesn't exist
      .jsx
        C:\absolute\path\to\app-container\my-vue-app\src\views\App.jsx doesn't exist
      .css
        C:\absolute\path\to\app-container\my-vue-app\src\views\App.css doesn't exist
      .scss
        C:\absolute\path\to\app-container\my-vue-app\src\views\App.scss doesn't exist
      .sass
        C:\absolute\path\to\app-container\my-vue-app\src\views\App.sass doesn't exist
      .vue
        C:\absolute\path\to\app-container\my-vue-app\src\views\App.vue doesn't exist
      as directory
        C:\absolute\path\to\app-container\my-vue-app\src\views\App doesn't exist

...
webpack:///./vue-platform-app/src/views/Home.vue?./node_modules/ts-loader!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist??ref--13-0:4
!(function webpackMissingModule() { var e = new Error("Cannot find module './App'"); e.code = 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'; throw e; }());
                                                                                                                  ^

Error: Cannot find module './App'
    at webpackMissingModule (webpack:///./my-vue-app/src/views/Home.vue?./node_modules/ts-loader!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist??ref--13-0:4:45)
    at eval (webpack:///./my-vue-app/src/views/Home.vue?./node_modules/ts-loader!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist??ref--13-0:4:125)
```

This error only happens when I import `App.ts` from my Node app. If I just do `yarn run serve` in `/my-vue-app`, it compiles perfectly.

Also, using `@/App`, it tries searching for it as a module, in `/my-vue-app/node_modules` as well as `/node_modules` in project root.

For reference, here is my `webpack.server.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
    entry: './server/index.js',
    target: 'node',

    externals: [nodeExternals()],

    output: {
        path: path.resolve('server-build'),
        filename: 'index.js',
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js', '.jsx', '.css', '.scss', '.sass', '.vue']
    },

    plugins: [new VueLoaderPlugin(), ...],

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader',
            },
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                options: {
                    'presets': [
                        '@babel/preset-env',
                        '@babel/preset-react',
                    ],
                    'plugins': [
                        '@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx',
                        '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
                    ],
                },
            },
            ...
        ],
    },
};
```

Here is my `.babelrc.json` in project root:

```json
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx"
    ]
}
```

And here is `babel.config.js` in `/my-vue-app`

```js
module.exports = {
  extends: '../.babelrc',
  presets: [
    '@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset'
  ]
}
```

`tsconfig.json` in project root:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dist/",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "module": "esnext",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "importHelpers": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "target": "es5",
        "jsx": "react",
        "allowJs": true,
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "@/*": [
                "vue-platform-app/src/*"
            ]
        },
        "types": [
            "webpack-env"
        ],
        "lib": [
            "esnext",
            "dom",
            "dom.iterable",
            "scripthost"
        ]
    }
}
```

`tsconfig.json` in `/my-vue-app` (generated by `vue create`):

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": [
      "webpack-env"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ],
    },
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

The following versions of these modules are installed in both `/package.json` and `/my-vue-app/package.json` (for good measure):

```
"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.33.0",
"@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.33.0",
"@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.5.11",
"@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^5.0.0-alpha.5",
"@vue/cli-plugin-pwa": "^5.0.0-alpha.5",
"@vue/cli-plugin-router": "^5.0.0-alpha.5",
"@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "^5.0.0-alpha.5",
"@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
"@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "3"
"typescript": "~3.9.3"
"vue": "^3.0.6",
```

`webpack-cli@^4.5.0` is installed in project root.

The only two solutions I have been able to come up with are including an absolute path the to file (which is horribly messy), or using `// @ts-ignore` above `import App from "App.ts";` (which leads to lots of other bugs/means no TS type checking).

What can I do to import this normally? I've almost certainly messed up *something* in one of my config files - how can I resolve the issue?

Comment: From the error message it seems the error is thrown when Webpack is processing `src/views/Home.vue`, not `main.ts` as you suggest...

Comment: Also if you are using `@` alias, it needs to be defined in both environments. For client bundle it is defined by Vue CLI webpack config. For server bundle (`webpack.server.js`) you need to define it yourself...

Comment: @MichalLevý surely `"@/*": ["vue-platform-app/src/*"]` in top-level `tsconfig.json` would do that?

Comment: I don't thinks so. That's TS config, not Webpack...

Comment: @MichalLevý Also regarding it being in `Home.vue` - that's true; I hadn't noticed that - but it looks quite strange. There's no imports in `Home.vue` other than the default `import HelloWorld from 'src/components/HelloWorld.vue';` (which is in the example project from `vue start`). And even after removing that import/the references to the component, the same error remains.

Comment: @MichalLevý RE TS Config - what do you mean? Where could I put it in the webpack config? Surely `ts-loader` just uses `tsconfig.json` to get its options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `@` alias in the Vue code, it needs to be defined in both environments. For client bundle it is defined by Vue CLI webpack config. For server bundle you need to define it by yourself...

`webpack.server.js`

```js
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {

  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, './vue-platform-app/src')
    },
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js', '.jsx', '.css', '.scss', '.sass', '.vue']
  },
}
```

Comment: `./vue-platform-app/src` resolves to `C:\Users\...\vue-platform-app\src\views\vue-platform-app\src`, while `/vue-platform-app/src` resolves just to `/vue-platform-app/src` (with no `C:` leading up to it) and claims that it can't find the module.

Comment: Definitely strange. Can you try updated code? ....this will make it absolute path